# What is the use of creating objects on the free store?

Tags: c++, constructor, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

```
void fun()
{
    A *a = new A;   //Here A is a class
}                   //a should be deleted in fun()'s scope

int main()
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

The object created exists on the free store and cannot be used by the main() function. The why should the objects be created on the free store. Yes we can pass the object reference to the main function but we can even pass a copy of the object(even when not created using the new operator). Then what's the exact use of the new and delete operator?

Comment: coz free store has more free space

Comment: I think that is the single reason for existence of free store (heap) - allocation of theoretically as much memory as is available via RAM.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi More than that. as much memory as addressable for your current memory model, depending on how much virtual storage you have. A 4GB 32bit address space is easily reachable on modern systems. (64bit, heh, not quite so easy =)

Comment: It also has a different lifetime: it is not bound to the scope, you get to decide for how long the object lives.

Comment: @juanchopanza The lifetime is the usual reason.  Although as the original poster points out, copying is normally preferable to dynamic allocation if the objects have value semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, there is none, and it isn't good practice to
use dynamic allocation.  Dynamic allocation is used when objects
have identity (or cannot be copied for some other reason), and
the lifetime of the object does *not* correspond to some
pre-determined lifetime, like static or auto.  Dynamic
allocation may also be used in a few cases where copying is
expensive, and the profiler shows that the copying is
a bottleneck; in such cases, using dynamic allocation and
copying a pointer may remove the bottleneck.  (But this should
never be done until profiling shows it necessary.)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: to allocate memory at runtime.

For more information consider: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: I can't believe I'm going to up-vote an answer that has a weblink to cplusplus.com. Somebody stop me.

Comment: @Sambuca You should! You bring evil to this... um... peaceful forum. That's it... Uh, I warn you! Don't ever do that again! :p

Comment: @WhozCraig They could have probably used [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Comment: The answer is wrong, and the link is to a site notorious for its errors.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Usually, it's not needed - explicitly. Sure, there's another answer saying "to allocate memory at runtime" and a similar comment. But you can achieve the same with `std::vector<>`, `std::string` etc. They'll do all that memory stuff behind the scenes for you, at the right moments.

That's one reason for `new/delete` - it's useful to implement some classes.

You mention that copies of objects can be passed. That can be a bit expensive, so for optimization purposes it can be worthwhile to replace the most expensive copies with `new/delete`. There are tools called "profilers" which can be used to identify which copies are expensive.

A third reason is polymorphism. You may have code similar to `Base* ptr = (foo>7) ? new Derived1 : new Derived2(foo);` where you don't know up front what object you will need, just how it should behave. Since the size of `Derived1` and `Derived2` are generally unrelated, you only know at runtime how much memory you need.

Answer (score 0):

Important reason is how [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) works. It has only push and pop operations. You can not release something in stack, before you have released everything pushed after it. Or to put it another way, if something is released from stack, such as function call's stack frame when function returns, then all memory above it in stack will be released also (and you'd better make sure it gets destructed properly, see below).

Programs generally need to store data independent of stack. There are two ways: allocate memory at compile time, as [static data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation), or allocate it in [free store, also called heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap).

It would certainly be possible to have several stacks, and in fact this is commonly done too, when convenient and useful. But it is done by using a stack container variable, with type such as [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/), then using that as extra stack for data only. Common processor architectures have just one "native" stack per process/thread, and that is used for function calls and stack variables, these extra stacks are always separate and created by the program code, just plain data structures same as lists, maps etc.

---

About code in your question, a point to make is that in modern C++ a naked `new` is generally frowned upon. You should use a RAII mechansim such as a smart pointer:

```
void fun()
{
    auto a = std::unique_ptr<A>{ new A };   // C++11 syntax
    // object is automatically destroyed when a goes out of scope, no leak
    // note: heap should be used like this only if there's a reason, including:
    // - A is big, and might conceivably overflow the stack
    // - ownership of object may get moved and outlive the unique_ptr

}
```

And your specific question "*The object created exists on the free store and cannot be used by the main() function. The why should the objects be created on the free store.*", well, in the question code, it should not be created in free store, there's no reason. It should be just plain automatic variable which gets automatically destructed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Your second point is completely wrong.  In many of the cases where dynamic allocation _is_ appropriate, there's not necessarily a problem with using `new` directly.  Your code is a good example of both abuse of `new` (the object shouldn't be allocated dynamically to begin with) and abuse of `auto`: if there was a valid motivation for using `new` and `unique_ptr`, something like `std::unique_ptr<A> a( new A );` (or `std::unique_ptr<A> a{ new A };`) would be far preferable.

Comment: @JamesKanze I said in text below that question object should not be created in heap... but I expanded the comment in code snippet to make this more clear. And using bare `new`, IOW not using RAII, in modern C++ is nearly always not the right thing. Also, this is not abuse of auto, that is *a* modern syntax which a developer is free to prefer (IOW, matter of opinion, subjective).

Comment: @JamesKanze a link which includes dicussion of the `auto a = ...` syntax: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: The abuse of `auto` makes the code hard to read and to understand, and can introduce subtle bugs.  It's fine in certain contexts (e.g. iterators obtained directly from `container.begin()`), but globally, it is more of an anti-pattern.  And if RAII would work for an allocation, you probably shouldn't be allocating.  (There are exceptions, and it's not rare to put a new'ed object in a `unique_ptr` temporarily, if it needs some processing post-construction, before becoming generally usable.  But it's not a good general rule either.)

Comment: And the article you cite contains a lot of hand waving, but ignores most of the concrete issues.  Don't confuse good writing with good software engineering.

Comment: @JamesKanze I doubt you have difficulty in reading or understanding that declaration, so by that definition it's not abuse of `auto`... Only difficulty is if you're not used to that style, which should take like 5 minutes to get over, or if it is not consistent with other code in the same code base, in which case stay consistent of course. And coding style is largely a subjective thing, I doubt you will find an article opposing the style in my answer, which doesn't contain equal amount of hand-waving.

Comment: @JamesKanze About not using RAII... I'd say, if in new C++11 code you do `delete` anywhere except *inside* some kind of memory management implementation (such as a custom smart pointer, custom Deleter, or a base class of a parent-child object ownership hierarchy), you're doing it wrong. For cases where you'd traditionally have explicit `delete`, use `std::unique_ptr::reset()` or equivalent. Just no reason not to, many reasons (consistent memory managemnt, avoiding classic bugs with memory leaks and dangling pointers) to do so.

Comment: Most of the `delete` in most of my applications have been `delete this`.  For cases where the constructor cannot put an object in a fully usable state, so that it will receive the notifications which might cause it to do `delete this`, holding it in an `std::unique_ptr` until it is fully active is a good idea (with the `reset` once it is ready).  But it's not something you should be doing systematically.  Most of the cases I see where people are using `unique_ptr` would be better handled by not using dynamic allocation at all.